# File is being used by another process on generating thumbnail

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream

I'm working on file manager project. I need to generate thumbnail if file is of image type. i'm able to get by using `IHttpHandler` with method

```
  Sytem.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImage(),
```

**Here is some code**

```
Hashtable ht;
            ht = new Hashtable();
            using (FileStream fInfo = new FileStream(context.Server.MapPath(url), FileMode.Open))
            {
                byte[] bFile;
                bFile = GenerateThumbnail(fInfo, XLen, YLen);
                ht.Add(id, bFile);
                fInfo.Close();

                Byte[] arrImg = (byte[])ht[id];
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(arrImg);
                context.Response.End();
            }
    private byte[] GenerateThumbnail(Stream fStream, string xLen, string yLen)
    {
        using (Image img = Image.FromStream(fStream))
        {
            Image thumbnailImage = img.GetThumbnailImage(int.Parse(xLen), int.Parse(yLen), new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero);

            using (MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                thumbnailImage.Save(imageStream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                byte[] imageContent = new Byte[imageStream.Length];
                imageStream.Position = 0;
                imageStream.Read(imageContent, 0, (int)imageStream.Length);
                return imageContent;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem**

Newly uploaded file on genrating thumb throwing expection : being used by another process, after sometime its shows the thumbnail. Q. where im missing to close the stream  ?

Comment: I think this is because when you create the file, something else does something with it (such as a virus scan) or the file is not released quick enough. To get around this, you can just add a Sleep(0001)

Comment: Do you have the indexing service active on the server?

Comment: @daverook if im using not the handler, its running fine(that mean there is nothing like virus), and where to add Sleep(0001)

Comment: @GrantThomas i've not idea about that, can you explain please?